# Characterizing the incidence graphs that correspond to a system of points and lines in the plane

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-geometry

The incidence graph of a system of points and lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the bipartite graph with partite sets $P, L$, where $P$ corresponds to the points, $L$ corresponds to the lines, and we add the edge $(p, \ell) \in P \times L$ to the graph if and only if line $\ell$ passes through point $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  (We will assume that our points and lines are distinct.)

Are there any characterizations of the family of all incidence graphs of systems of points and lines (e.g., in terms of forbidden subgraphs or minors)? For example, we know that these graphs do not contain a $K_{2, 2}$ subgraph, but this is not sufficient for a complete characterization.

Alternatively, can we decide if a graph belongs to this family in polynomial time or is this problem NP-hard?

Comment: What are some other examples of forbidden subgraphs?

Comment: We know that any bipartite graph with girth > 4 and  $\gg n^{4/3}$ edges is forbidden by the  Szemerédi–Trotter theorem. So for example, the incidence graph of the finite field projective plane is forbidden. Unfortunately, I haven't found any small examples yet, but I will edit my post if I do.

Comment: I didn't know the  Szemerédi–Trotter theorem, but I guess it already follows from the Sylvester-Gallai theorem that the incidence graph of any finite projective plane or Steiner triple system (on more than $3$ points) is forbidden?